# Append new records in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a for loop that reads an excel and produces a data frame HYDRO_data_3 , example shown below
[image]

Then I want to append only the V2 records from each excel file to HYDRO_data_4 .
I have been using the following code:

HYDRO_data_4[length(HYDRO_data_4)+1]=HYDRO_data_3[2,]

but the result doesn't make any sense. below is a screen shot.
[image]

In short, how do I add record to a new data frame in a for loop?

thanks

look up on google to find answer

Comment: The `length` of a data frame is the number of columns. `HYDRO_data_4[length(HYDRO_data_4)+1]` is trying to add a new column (both because of the `length()` and because there is no `,` in the brackets `[]`), but `HYDRO_data_3[2,]` is a row. If you want to add a row to the bottom, `rbind` is simplest: `HYDRO_data_4 = rbind(HYDRO_data_4, HYDRO_data_3[2,])`

Comment: All that said, adding rows one-at-a-time in a `for` loop is a notorious performance killer. If you'd like help finding a better solution, share a small reproducible example and we can try to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.